# How to use php get string between two characters at 3rd row?

Tags: php

```
   $abc = "['Fund', 'Amount'],
    ['Seed Fund (Investor)', 50000],
    ['Loan Fund (Spartan)', 50000],
    ['Profit (Investor)', 3000],";
```

How to use php to get "Loan Fund (Spartan)" and 50000 from string above?

using foreach loop?

using array?

using $substring()?

any better solution?

Comment: What is the source? Is that an array with missing outer `[]` or a string? It's not JSON since there are no double quotes. Also show us what you have tried

Comment: ok i have updated the question it is just a string hold by variable $abc

Comment: There are so many different ways to do something like this. Would be awesome to see what you have tried and the results (and any errors) you got.

Comment: `it is just a string`...sure, we can see that - but the point of charlieftl's question was really: how did it come to be in that specific format? It's not a recognised format such as JSON where you could trivially use existing functions to decode it into a PHP object and then access the properties. (It's nearly JSON, as mentioned above, but it isn't quite valid due to the missing outer brackets). If there's no specific reason why the data is in that format, then consider changing it to a well-known format - then you don't have to figure out your own way of parsing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a string, you can't loop it - but you can turn it into an array and then loop it:

```
// Prepare the string to represent a JSON object
$abc = str_replace("'", '"', trim($abc, ','));

// Actually turn it into a string representation of a JSON object
$abc = '[['.$abc.']]';

// Turn it into an array by json_decoding it
$abc = json_decode($abc, true);

// Grab the initial data
$abc = array_pop($abc);

// Walk the data
foreach ($abc as $set) {

    if (in_array('Loan Fund (Spartan)', $set)) {

        ...
    }
}
```

Though this was just for the fun of it - try to get a more useful data representation (an array, a real JSON object/string) in the first place.